# How to prevent a user from moving the size of a column in QtableWidget using Python and Qt?

Tags: python, qt, qt-creator, qtablewidget

I created a `QTableWidget` whith two columns in Qt Creator.

I already found out how to set the width of a column with the `setColumnWidth()` function. But in my GUI the user can still change the width of columns. How can I set the width to a fixed size and forbid the user to modify it?

Comment: Use `table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(...)` (or `setResizeMode` in older Qt versions) with appropriate [resize mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(...)` (or `setResizeMode` in older Qt versions) with appropriate [resize mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum).